# I need to navigate windows forms based on login password

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows, winforms

this is the code i have used to validate both username and password from the database. but it always navigates to the first if condition. But is HR group has the same password and SW dev group has the same password. i need to validate the  password and need to navigate to the Form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string usrnm = txtusrnm.Text;
    string pass = txtpass.Text;
    SqlDataReader reader = null;

    string qry = "select username, password from login where username=@username and password=@password";
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusrnm.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpass.Text);

    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader != null ||reader.HasRows)
    {
        //if username is matching 
        MessageBox.Show("Redirecting to HR..");
        frm_hr fhr = new frm_hr();
        fhr.Show();
        this.Hide();   
    }
    else
    {
        //if not matching do something
        MessageBox.Show("Redirecting to Software Developer..");
        frm_swdev fsw = new frm_swdev();
        fsw.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why added `reader != null` ? `reader.HasRows` is enough!

Comment: To further clarify Harshit's comment, your condition should be **AND**, not **OR**: `reader != null && reader.HasRows`. In this case, `reader` will never be null, so your condition can be simplified to `reader.HasRows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code there is this :

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader != null ||reader.HasRows)
```

this will always be true, because reader will always != null

change it to

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate idea to reader.HasRows - change your query to count the number of rows that contain the username/password, then you will always return a value of 0 or 1...

```
string qry = "select count(*) from login where username=@username and password=@password";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusrnm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpass.Text);

int iValue = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```